# How do I grab a x-www-form-urlencoded jpg in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, put

My Manager is using [MIT App Inventor](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/) to build an Android App.
Part of that app he wants to post or put a JPG to his Express Js site using the [postFile](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/other.html#Web), or [putFile](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/other.html#Web) components.

When we `console.log(req)` on the express server, it appears that MIT App Inventor is not handling the jpg that is uploaded as multipart/form-data but as x-www-form-urlencoded data.

Every time a file gets written to the filesystem with the name of the uploaded file on the server and we open it, All we see is [Object Object].

It does not appear that we can use multer, or busyboy, or fileupload at all because these all only handle multipart/form-data.  What can we do to convert the req.body back to a jpg when we save the file?

Comment: MIT? Ask your manager?!

Comment: Is it encoded as a base64 string? Nodejs can write it to disk if you specify `base64` encoding

Comment: How can I tell if it is a base64 string?